# Set multiple variables from 1 input

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

The user puts in one input (2 words, space as delimiter), and that is set to 2 variables.

```
@echo off
set /p input=Input:
set var1=%input%
set var2=%input2%
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
pause
```

That of course won't work, but that's all I know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `for` loop to split the string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "input=Input: "
set count=0
for %%a in (%input%) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set var!count!=%%a
)
echo found %count% words:
set var
```

Note: this may fail with some special characters in the input string.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the "for" command, so I'm struggling a bit.

If someone inputs "test1 test2" how do I separate them? I apologize how I come off, the last thing I want is to be spoon fed the answer, but I'm drawing blanks in my ol' noggin.

EDIT: I'M AN IDIOT, JUST FIGURED IT OUT. DISREGARD.

Comment: `for` splits at standard delimiters `Space`, `TAB` and `,;=`, so there is no more manual work to do for you. See [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

A little trickery using string substitution with the SET command. This will allow multiple space delimited strings to be entered and it will number them up accordingly.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p "input=Input: "
set i=1
set "var!i!=%input: =" & set /A i+=1 & set "var!i!=%"
set var
pause
```